# How do you insert SQL data into a database using Python?

Tags: python, sql, raspberry-pi

I am attempting to create a program that reads 3 sensors from a raspberry pi sense hat, and insert those values into a sql database, using python. When I execute the program, no errors are given, but when I try to select the data using python, or even going into the database itself, the data is nowhere to be found, I believe the data isn't being properly written. How would I go about correcting this?

```
import sqlite3
import datetime
from sense_hat import SenseHat

sense = SenseHat()
sensePressure = int(sense.get_pressure())
senseTemp = int(sense.get_temperature() * 1.8 + 32 - 18.85)
senseHumidity = int(sense.get_humidity())
currDateTime = datetime.datetime.now()

COUNT = 1
conn = sqlite3.connect('sense.db')

c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("INSERT INTO atmos (ITEM, DATETIME, TEMPERATURE, HUMIDITY, PRESSURE) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, 
?)", (COUNT, currDateTime, senseTemp, sensePressure, senseHumidity))

conn.commit()

conn.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are writing to any SQL database, you will be better of using the `pyodbc` library it is quite effective and very easy to use :

```
  import pyodbc
  connection = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                  'Server=server_name;'
                  'Database=db_name;'
                  'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

  cursor = connection.cursor()
  cursor.execute("INSERT INTO atmos (ITEM, DATETIME, TEMPERATURE, HUMIDITY, PRESSURE) 
                  VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", COUNT, currDateTime, senseTemp, 
                  sensePressure, senseHumidity)
```